# Unmap locally a mapping from .vimrc

Tags: key-bindings, buffers

Let's say I have the following line in my `.vimrc`:

```
noremap ge w
```

Sometimes I want to unmap it locally to the current buffer, so I run:
`:unmap <buffer> ge`. When I do this, I get an error message that the mapping doesn't exist. I understand that the mapping doesn't exist specifically for the current buffer only but it exist in all the buffers I will ever open in this session, I can see the mapping is active when I run `:verb map ge` but not when I run `:verb map <buffer> ge`.

It seems like running `unmap <buffer>` can only undo commands containing `map <buffer>`. I don't want to `noremap ge <nop>` because that will delete the original key-sequence's command. Is it possible to unmap a mapping from `.vimrc` only in the current `<buffer>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
:nnoremap <buffer> ge ge
```

To map the command back to original for this buffer.